# How to measure mass of a Mosquito?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, measurements

I though of a solution, by taking large number of mosquito and then measuring their mass and then averaging over, to get mass of a single mosquito.
Is there anything other way than this?

Answer (score 1):

there are precision microbalances (Mettler is one popular brand) used in chemistry laboratories than can accurately weigh single mosquitoes, but they have to be dead.

Comment: A mosquito weighs about 5 mg, but microbalances weigh also 500 µg, 50 µg and even 5 µg.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of weighing many mosquitoes might be simpler and more precise, since it is easy to catch many mosquitoes with  pheromone traps, where the mosquitoes will be stuck to a surface. It must be ensured that dust and other material does not stick to the trap (trap in box with small downward opening hanging on ceiling in a clean room). Disadvantage is to catch only those that are sexually attracted, i.e.  of a specific sex/age. So it probably won't yield an average weight of all mosquitoes, by far the most dangerous animal on this planet in terms of victims.